# incorporating ldap plugin with grails application

Tags: grails, ldap

I have a grails application and I've added the `spring security ldap plugin`. Everything works fine from local host when I build the application in an `IDE` but when i deploy a war file, I get the following error

```
''2014-06-17 11:15:06,412 [Thread-29] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
'2014-06-17 11:15:06,412 [Thread-29] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
'2014-06-17 11:15:06,413 [Thread-29] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
'2014-06-17 11:15:06,413 [Thread-29] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapAuthoritiesPopulator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource.setAuthenticationStrategy(Lorg/springframework/ldap/core/support/DirContextAuthenticationStrategy;)V
        ... 5 more
'2014-06-17 11:15:06,422 [stop children - Catalina:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/SpineProcedures-0.1,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none] WARN  lifecycle.ShutdownOperations  - Error occurred running shutdown operation: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
'java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

## external configuration file

```
environments {
    development {
        println("Overriding development environment configuration")

        // Common values
        def ldapDn = 'exampleDN'
        def ldapPassword = 'examplePW'
        def ldapUrl = 'ldap://<domain>.location.example.edu'
        def ldapBase = 'OU=exampleDomain,OU=Non-Standard,DC=<domain>,DC=location,DC=example,DC=edu'

        // Spring Security
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = ldapDn
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = ldapPassword
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = ldapUrl

        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = ldapBase
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = ldapBase

        // LDAP
        ldap {
            directories {
                directory1 {
                    url = ldapUrl
                    base = ldapBase
                    userDn = ldapDn
                    password = ldapPassword
                }
            }
        }

        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/Website"
    }
    test {
        println("Overriding test environment configuration")
    }
    production {
        println("Overriding production environment configuration")

        // Common values
        def ldapDn = 'exampleDN'
        def ldapPassword = 'examplePW'
        def ldapUrl = 'ldap://<domain>.location.example.edu'
        def ldapBase = 'OU=exampleDomain,OU=Non-Standard,DC=<domain>,DC=location,DC=example,DC=edu'

        // Spring Security
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = ldapDn
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = ldapPassword
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = ldapUrl

        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = ldapBase
        grails.plugins.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = ldapBase

        // LDAP
        ldap {
            directories {
                directory1 {
                    url = ldapUrl
                    base = ldapBase
                    userDn = ldapDn
                    password = ldapPassword
                }
            }
        }

        // Data source
        dataSource {
            username = "spineproc"
            password = "spineproc"
            url      = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/spine_proc_0-1"
        }

        grails.serverURL = "https://r-spineproc.<domain>.location.example.edu/SpineProcedures-0.1"

        // Turn on DBConsole
        grails.dbconsole.enabled

        // Turn on the DBDoc controller
        grails.plugin.databasemigration.dbDocController.enabled = true
    }


}
```

Could use some advice, thanks.

Comment: Do you have any LDAP configurations in your environment-specific configuration sections? By default, Grails will build the WAR with the "production" environment. My best guess would be that there are configurations you included for development, but not production.

Comment: The developer and production environment settings have the same configurations far as ldap specific values.

Comment: Sorry. I probably should've read your entire stack trace before commenting initially. This looks like a Spring version mismatch. I believe the latest Spring Security LDAP Plugin for grails uses Spring Security LDAP 3.2.0-RC1. My *new* guess would be that there is a conflicting version somewhere on your Tomcat classpath. Make sure you haven't added libraries to the /lib folder.

Comment: no problem, you're feedback is spot on. I've already resolved the issue. Forgot to answer my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by deleting the

`compile ":ldap:0.8.2"`

plugin in my buildConfig file

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `spring-security-ldap` is clashing with `spring-ldap` which is pulled by `ldap` plugin.
Removing `ldap` plugin is not a solution for a someone who needs to run LDAP queries.

The plugin `ldap:0.8.2` comes with libraries fixed in `/lib` folder. We want to remove `spring-ldap-1.2.1.jar` to solve libraries clash. To avoid packaging it in the war file we have to remove it explicitly (in `BuildConfig.groovy`).

```
    grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
            delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/spring-ldap-1.2.1.jar")
    }
```

This makes `ldap` to use `spring-ldap-core` provided by `sping-security-ldap`, assuming we include it as a plugin.

```
    +--- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2
    |    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:3.2.0.RC1
    |    \--- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:1.3.2.RELEASE
```